# Docker files are clogging up my filesystem

Tags: disk-usage, docker

On my Linux machine, the home directory I'm running the containers from is limited to 50GB. After a little more investigation into why my file system was full, I noticed that the `/var/lib/docker/` directory was taking up 44GB of space. Can anyone explain to me, why this is happening? The docker-compose file I'm running only starts one container.

```
grafana:
  image: grafana/grafana:6.2.5
  container_name: grafana2
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  environment:
    - TERM=linux
    #- CONF_DIR=/etc/grafana
    #- GF_PATHS_CONFIG=/etc/grafana/grafana.ini
    #- GF_AUTH_LDAP_ENABLED=true
    #- GF_AUTH_LDAP_CONFIG_FILE=/etc/grafana/ldap.toml
    - GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=grafana-clock-panel,briangann-gauge-panel,natel-plotly-panel,grafana-simple-json-datasource,grafana-piechart-panel,ryantxu-annolist-panel,michaeldmoore-annunciator-panel,jdbranham-diagram-panel,natel-discrete-panel,zuburqan-parity-report-panel,snuids-radar-panel
  volumes:
    -  /etc/grafana/grafana.ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini
    #-  /var/log/grafana:/var/log/grafana
    #-  /etc/grafana/ldap.toml:/etc/grafana/ldap.toml
    - /grafana/provisioning/:/etc/grafana/provisioning/
```

I have been deleting the logs but it hasn't seemed to be a viable solution, as it only clears up about 6GB of space and then it's only a matter of time before it fills back up again.

Now, I do have another file system on the server that has 2TB disk space called `/afs`.

- Is it possible to allocate all the content of `/var/lib/docker/` to there?
- Can this be done in the `docker-compose` file or is it to do with how
  docker was installed?
- Does docker have to be setup on the `/afs`? Or could a symlink be setup to point to `/afs` from `/var/lib/docker`?

sudo docker ps --all 
CONTAINER ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NAMES
 6f6b0274a89d grafana/grafana:6.2.5 "/run.sh" 5 months ago Up 2 hours 0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp grafana2


sudo docker image ls 
REPOSITORY TAG IMAGE ID CREATED SIZE grafana/grafana 6.2.5 c912f3f026ed 12 months ago 249MB

Comment: Have you checked the output of `docker image ls` and `docker ps --all`?

Comment: Edit your question to add information,  and use the formatting tools. Comments are for US to ask YOU to improve your Question, to help us help you.